# How to bundle jenkins plugins into jenkins.war

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to bundle some plugins into Jenkins.war, but I'm unsure how to exactly.  I've been referencing this page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bundling+plugins+with+Jenkins, but I'm confused about the specifics.  If I just move the .hpi files from the plugins I want into /WEB-INF/plugins/, what other steps would I have to do to actually get a new .war file?  Should I run the pom file provided, and if so, where/how should I run it?  Anything else I should make sure I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for one time bundlling your plugins into jenkins.war, then just open war file in 7-zip or any archive extracter then copy the plugins into /WEB-INF/plugins/ and save it. It should work fine.

If you want to automatically bundle plugins with newer changes, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bundling+plugins+with+Jenkins explains how your plugin pom.xml should look and contents of your Ant target file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Just a quick follow up: Do I only need to copy in the .hpi files for the plugin to work?

Comment: @MichaelA: Yes. You need to copy only .hpi files into war.