# How to bundle jenkins jobs into jenkins.war

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to bundle some jobs into Jenkins.war, but I'm not sure whether it is possible or not. I have found a way to bundle plugins here, [How to bundle jenkins plugins into jenkins.war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067378/how-to-bundle-jenkins-plugins-into-jenkins-war). I would like to know whether there is a similar way to bundle jobs as well.

Comment: Why would you want to include jobs in the war ? Are you building your own custom Jenkins? Generally, you'd want to keep separate the war (as provided by jenkins.io), the static configuration (plugins, all your settings) and the dynamic portion (your jobs).

Comment: @IanW Yes, I'm building my own custom Jenkins with some sample jobs

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be, to create a DockerFile and use that war file in the command. you can specify all bunch of commands after that, like pre-configured some useful plugins, install some utilities and import some job templates. When you will spin up a container using that docker file, it will have all those artifacts including jobs that you have specified. I hope it helps!